# List files that contains telephone numbers in a unix directory

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

i have a directory called testDir and it contains 1000 file, some of them contains telephone numbers and some of them doesn't, the telephone number format is "12-3456789"
how to get the number of files that contains telephone numbers ?

**EDIT:** i am not familiar with unix, so i couldn't answer the question.

Comment: The question would be better if it contained your attempt at a solution.

Comment: Michal, if he's not even familiar with any unix flavour it's understandable if he doesn't even know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution could be:

```
 grep -lE "[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7}" * | wc -l
```

**EDIT:**

`grep` seeks for pattern in files.
-E activates regular expressions (you could use egrep instead)
-l filters grep results, only the file name will be printed

wc counts
-l lines will be count (-w counts words, but it could provide incorrect results in case of spaces in filenames)

Comment: can you please provide little explanation for the command, what does -le and wc and -l means ? and is this command lists the files or counts them ?

Comment: @fresh_dev: see edit; for more information: <code>man grep</code> and <code>man wc</code>